# How to pass two arrays to $options parameter of stream_context_create($options)?

Tags: php, ssl

Now i pass an array inside $options to stream_context_create which is the next one:

```
$options = array('http' => array(
        'method'=>'POST',
           'header'=>
  "Accept-language: en\r\n".
  "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",      'content'=>http_build_query(array('partida'=>$partida,'dataInici'=>$dataInici,'dataFi'=>$dataFi,'usuari'=>$_SESSION["usuari"]))));
```

And the php gaves me an error of "PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"

And i found a possible solution to this which is pass to stream_context_create($options) inside $options an array like this:

```
$arrContextOptions=array(
"ssl"=>array(
    "cafile" => "/cacert.pem",
    "verify_peer"=> true,
    "verify_peer_name"=> true,
),);
```

But i don't know how to pass both arrays inside $options.

Comment: [array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge)? Or just put it in the $options array in the first place (if it's an option)

Comment: Still gaves me the same error. I don't know if stream_context_create can accept two arrays...

Comment: Show all the relevant code. And shouldn't those `true`s be `false` to not fail on unverified cert?

Comment: What? It takes _1_ options array, so give it one array, which should be basic PHP to achieve.

Comment: If i put it to false it doesn't give me the error but still doesn't work

Comment: What doesn't work? How does it not work? What is happening? What were you expecting? Show us the relevant code. Show us outputs. Show us errors logs, messages.

Comment: It is a big webpage and there's a lot of code, i'm trying to export a pdf with mpdf library and it doesn't work. And this ssl error is the only one that the log file gives me.